# is there a way to move launcher to the right side of screen in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

Is there a way to move the launcher to the right side of the screen in 14.04? everything that pops up in searches is only for moving to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move the dock in 14.04. While there are some unofficial plugins that make this possible (that have since seemed to vanish), it wasn't a native feature.

That feature was added in Ubuntu 16.04, which only supports moving to the bottom. The command to make this take effect is below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

Comment: He asking for ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @MohamedSlama I think he answered it well, but he didn't make enough of a distinction. I've edited the post to try to make the distinction more clear now.

Comment: Thanks. All I could find was moving it to the bottom so I figured I'd ask. I've also seen a couple plug ins too.

Comment: So what I ended up doing was creating some desktop icons. Usr/share/applications pick. Copy. Paste. Happy with that.